# How to go to next step programatically using ng2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Ng2-archwizard, what i want is to go to the next step using component.ts i mean with javascript function:

```
<wizard>
  <wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 1">
  Content of Step 1
  <button type="button" nextStep>Next Step</button>
  <button type="button" goToStep="2">Go directly to third Step</button>
</wizard-step>
<wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 2" optionalStep>
  Content of Step 2
  <button type="button" previousStep>Go to previous step</button>
  <button type="button" nextStep>Go to next step</button>
</wizard-step>
<wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 3">
  Content of Step 3
   <button type="button" previousStep>Previous Step</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="finishFunction()">Finish</button>
 >/wizard-step>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your component :

```
  // At the top of my component class that implements the <wizard>
  @ViewChild(WizardComponent)
  public wizard: WizardComponent;

  // then later, this works great
  this.wizard.model.navigationMode.goToStep(1)
```

Comment: i have to declare this.wizard.model.navigationMode.goToStep(1) in function ?

Comment: it gives this error :core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: WizardComponent is not defined

Comment: yes this works, thank you!  It would be good if these details are part of ng2-archwizard documentation.  One additional information is that the number in goToStep is not relative to the current wizard step rather it is the wizard number from its first page.

Comment: It is working when we want to go to next step, but I need to skip 2 steps and go to directly third step, is there any function available for this.